# Windows 8.1 Files missing after transferring to a newly created folder and pressing Ctrl+Z

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, data-recovery, debug

I had a few video files in a folder. I wanted to transfer the videos into a new folder, so I created a new folder just before I made the transfer.

I selected all of the videos and dragged them to the new folder. But one of the videos was playing in the background, so a prompt appeared saying the file is in use and could not be transferred, with options to "try again", "skip", and "cancel". I clicked cancel. The video that was playing wasn't transferred to the new folder, while the rest are now in the new folder.

I wanted to undo the transfer and move all of the videos back to the original folder. So I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo. But instead of moving the files back from the new folder to the original folder, windows explorer deleted (or "uncreated"?) the new folder, with all the videos in it.

Now I am left with the only video that didn't make the transfer in the original folder and all the other videos are missing. I did press redo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) but all it did was to create a new folder without anything inside.

Things I've tried but were unsuccessful:

- Looking for the videos in recycle bin
- Searching the computer for the videos to make sure they are not hiding in other folders
- Search with data recovery software
- Send and demonstrate the problem to multiple technicians
- Posted the problem in Microsoft forum, support engineer was unable to come up with solutions

I'm still unable to recover any of the missing files. Any idea what else can I do to try to recover the videos?

Answer (score 0):

The files are deleted, i think with standard methods, you wont get them back.
Because the missing files where already written to the new directory, they should be recoverable by tools like [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva).

Comment: Thanks! But I tried Recuva before posting the question here. It couldn't even locate the missing files.

Comment: Did you try it on the source location too?

Comment: Yup. I scanned all the drives in my computer with deep scan option enabled.